# Softlayer snapshot creation failure (curl-windows)

Tags: windows, rest, curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Issuing rest call via cURL fails with "generic error"

curl --user "user:API_Key" "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/IBM02SEL155527/createSnapshot"

Value returned:
{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

-v options doesn't provide any additional information.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.
Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are getting is due that you need to send the id value of the blockstorage instead of the lun name.

For example:

```
curl -v --user "user:API_Key" "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/111111111/createSnapshot"
```

Comment: Unclear how to find the "device ID" as details of the Device name doesn't list this.  Check of hosts permitted to use the resource has the "device ID" field left blank.

Comment: Device ID available in the URL, trying this now.

Comment: Issue resolved, voted for correct answer but no rep means not displayed.